# Sagemaker, get spark dataframe from data image url on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, image-processing, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to obtain a sparkdataframe which contains the paths and image for all images in my data. The data is store as follow :
folder/image_category/image_n.jpg

I worked on a local jupyter notebook and got no problem with using following code:

`dataframe = spark.read.format("image").load(path)`

I need to do the same exercise using AWS sagemaker and S3. I created a bucket following the same pattern :
s3://my_bucket/folder/image_category/image_n.jpg

I've tried a lot of possible solutions i found online, based on boto3, s3fs and other stuff, but unfortunately i am still unable to make it work (and i am starting to lose faith ...).

Would anyone have something reliable i could base my work on ?